# Event Doesn't Show on the calendar (Full calendar) Laravel

Tags: laravel, fullcalendar

i'm using full calendar for a project in laravel. I can add an event on the database and it works fine but the event doesn't show on the calendar. What should i do?
Can someone help me please ? i'm new to this thank you in advance.

Here is My code:

***this is my view :***

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.css"/>
    @if(count($errors)> 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error )
            @endforeach
            <li>{{$error}}</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    @endif
    
    @if(\Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <p>{{ \Session::get('success') }}</p>
    </div>
    @endif
     
        <div id='calendar'>
       
             {!! $calendar->calendar() !!}
            {!! $calendar->script() !!}
                </div>
          
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

and this is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Event;

class EventController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
      $events=Event::all();
      $event=[];

    foreach($events as $row){
    $enddate=$row->end_date." 24:00:00";
    $events[]= \Calendar::event( 
    $row->title,
    true,
    new \DateTime($row->start_date),
    new \DateTime($row->end_date),
    $row->id,
    [
        'color'=>$row->color,
    ]
);

      }

$calendar= \Calendar::addEvents($event);
return view('admin.affaire_date',compact('events','calendar'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

public function display(){
    return view('admin.add_event');

}

    public function store(Request $request)

    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'title'=> 'required',
            'color'=> 'required',
            'start_date'=> 'required',
            'end_date'=> 'required',
            
        ]);
        $events = new Event;
        
        $events->title = $request ->input('title');
        $events->color= $request ->input('color');
        $events->start_date = $request ->input('start_date');
        $events->end_date= $request ->input('end_date');
    
          $events->save();   
           
        return redirect('/date')->with('success' ,'Events added');
    
    }
```

***My event Model:***

```
  <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Event extends Model
{
    protected $table ='events';
    protected $fillable =['title','color','start_date','end_date'];

}
```

***And my event view :***

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add event </h1>
        <form method="POST" action ="{{action('EventController@store')}}">
        {{csrf_field() }}
        <label for="">Enter name of </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Enter Name "/><br />
        <label for="">Enter Color</label> 
        <input type="color" class="form-control" name="color" placeholder="Enter color "/><br />
        <label for="">Enter Start Date of Event </label> 
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="start_date" placeholder="Enter Starting Date "/><br />
        <label for="">Enter Finishing Date of Event </label> 
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="end_date" placeholder="Enter Finishing Date "/><br />


        <input type="submit" class="brn btn-primary"  value="Add Event Data"/> 

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just so you know, you're using a _really_ old version of fullCalendar. if you're just using it for the first time it would make a lot more sense to use the latest version. Check the fullCalendar documentation on the website

Comment: Anyway we don't know why you can't see your new event because we can't see exactly what data it contains. Maybe the date is the wrong format, or something else went wrong. We need more details